# How to POST dependent AJAX drop down form data via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a form that has multiple drop down lists that must be dynamically populated (currently using AJAX) without refreshing the page. To make matters difficult, I am new to AJAX.

Once the end user has made all selections in the form, I need to update the database (MySQL) via a PHP script.

At the moment, I need help understanding how to pass (POST) the dependent drop down selections once they have been made.

**Here is the AJAX functions I have defined:**

```
    function getXMLHTTP() { //fuction to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }


    function getPool(divId) {       

        var strURL="findPool.php?division="+divId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('pooldiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }       
    }
    function getTeam(divId,poolId) {        
        var strURL="findTeam.php?division="+divId+"&pool="+poolId;
        //window.alert(poolId);
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('teamdiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
```

**Here is the form:**

```
<div class="box-content">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
    <?PHP
        //include 'session_start';

        include 'init.php';

        //$event_id = $_SESSION['event_id'];
        $event_id = 31;

        if(isset($_POST['division']))
        {
            $div_name = $_POST['division']; 
        } 
        if(isset($_POST['pool']))
        {
            $pool_name = $_POST['pool']; 
        } 
        if(isset($_POST['team']))
        {
            $team_name = $_POST['team']; 
        } 

        //echo "event id - $event_id<br>";
        echo "division name - $div_name<br>";
        echo "pool name - $pool_name<br>";
        echo "team name - $team_name<br>";


        echo "
        <tr>
            <td colspan=\"6\"><div align=\"left\"><font size=\"4\" face=\"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif\"><strong><u>Title</u></strong></td>\n
        </tr>\n";

        //Query to get number of teams for each division
        $query = "SELECT event_div.div_id, divisions.div_lname
                FROM event_div, divisions
                WHERE event_div.div_id = divisions.div_id
                AND event_div.event_id = $event_id
                ORDER BY divisions.div_order, event_div.div_id";

        //echo "<pre>".$query."</pre>";   // Leave this line for debugging the sql query.

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (!$result) 
        {
            echo "Could not run query: $query" . mysqli_error($conn);
            exit;
        }

        // Declare variables
        $div_id = array();
        $div_lname = array();

        /// Push data into the arrays
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            array_push ($div_id, $row[0]);
            array_push ($div_lname, $row[1]);
        }

        $div_count = count($div_id);                                        

        echo"
        <form method=\"post\" name=\"form1\">
        <fieldset>
            <tr>
                <td width=\"10%\">Division</td>\n
                <td width=\"20%\">\n
                <select class=\"form-control\" name=\"division\" onChange=\"getPool(this.value)\">
                <option value=\"\">Select Division</option>\n";

                for($i=0; $i<$div_count; $i++)
                {
                    echo "<option value=\"$div_id[$i]\">$div_lname[$i]</option>\n";
                }

        echo"</select>
                </td>\n
                <td width=\"10%\">CB&nbsp;</td>
                <td width=\"20%\">Option&nbsp;</td>
                <td width=\"20%\">Div&nbsp;</td>
                <td width=\"20%\">Pool&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>\n
            <tr style=\"\">
                <td>Pool</td>
                <td><div id=\"pooldiv\"></div></td>
                <td>CB&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Option&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Div&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Team&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style=\"\">
                <td>Team</td>
                <td><div id=\"teamdiv\"></div></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

        </fieldset>
        </form>";

     ?> 
    </table>
</div>
```

**Here is the PHP populating the first drop down:**

```
$event_id = 31;

$division=($_GET['division']);

$query = "
SELECT DISTINCT(et.pool_name), et.pool_num, dv.div_id 
FROM event_team AS et, divisions AS dv 
WHERE et.div_lname = dv.div_lname
AND dv.div_id = $division 
AND event_id = $event_id 
ORDER BY et.pool_num, et.pool_name DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

//echo "<pre>".$query."</pre>";  

if (!$result) 
{
    echo "Could not run query: $query" . mysqli_error($conn);
    //exit;
} 


echo "
<select class=\"form-control\" data-width=\"100px\" name=\"pool\" onchange=\"getTeam($division,this.value)\">
<option>Select Pool</option>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
{ echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>"; }
echo "
</select>";
```

**The second dropdown:**

```
$event_id = 31;

//$divisionId=($_GET['division']);
$poolId=($_GET['pool']);
//echo "poolId on findTeam = $poolId</br>";

$query = "SELECT team_name, team_id, pool_team_num 
          FROM event_team 
          WHERE event_id = $event_id 
          AND pool_name = \"$poolId\" 
          AND active = 1 ORDER BY pool_team_num";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

//echo "<pre>".$query."</pre>";  

if (!$result) 
{
    echo "Could not run query: $query" . mysqli_error($conn);
    //exit;
} 

echo "
<select class=\"form-control\" data-width=\"100px\" name=\"team\">
<option>Select Team</option>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
{ echo "<option value='$row[1]'>$row[0]</option>"; }
echo "
</select>";
```

***FINALLY... Here is my problem...*** I can't get the dependent drop downs to post to the page once the submit button is pressed. I am including a copy of the HTML source after form selections are made. ODDLY... the 2 divs updated by the AJAX function calls do NOT show anything in the HTML source

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
    <fieldset>
        <tr>
            <td width="10%">Division</td>
            <td width="20%">
            <select class="form-control" name="division" onChange="getPool(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select Division</option>
                <option value="3">Coed 4's A</option>
                <option value="1">Coed 4's B</option>
                <option value="4">Coed 4's Rec</option>
                <option value="5">Coed 6's B</option>
                <option value="6">Coed 6's Rec</option>
                <option value="11">Mens 3's Open</option>
                <option value="10">Mens 3's AA</option>
                <option value="9">Mens 3's A</option>
                <option value="7">Mens 3's BB</option>
                <option value="8">Mens 3's B</option>
                <option value="24">Womens 3's AA</option>
                <option value="14">Womens 3's A</option>
                <option value="13">Womens 3's BB</option>
                <option value="12">Womens 3's B</option>
                <option value="84">Spectator Pass</option>
                <option value="83">Coed 2's Cornhole</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td width="10%">CB&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="20%">Option&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="20%">Div&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="20%">Pool&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
            <td>Pool</td>
            <td><div id="pooldiv"></div></td>
            <td>CB&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Option&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Div&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Team&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
            <td>Team</td>
            <td><div id="teamdiv"></div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions on how to POST the "missing" dependent drop down selections OR if there is a better or different approach, I would appreciate any and all feedback.

I know this is alot to pour over and really appreciate anyone/everyone taking the time to help!!!

Cheers,

Mirlynn

Comment: It looks like you are not replacing the default HTML for pool and team with the result of the AJAX calls, therefore there is no data to return on submit

Comment: Have you found the javascript debugger in all good browsers. Use that, set a breakpoint on the line that loads the returned data into the relevant div and see what is actually happening. You can also use it to view variable content

Comment: Your form do not have any action. Are you elsewhere triggering the post action?